# ostream_iterator for Binary Output

Tags: c++, file-io, iterator, fstream, binaryfiles

I want to be able to use an [`ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) to stream to a binary file. But the `ostream_iterator` uses a [FormattedOuputFunction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/FormattedOutputFunction) so it will write ASCII, not binary:

> `std::ostream_iterator` is a single-pass OutputIterator that writes successive objects of type `T` into the `std::basic_ostream` object for which it was constructed, using `operator<<`

Beyond writing my own iterator is there a way to use an iterator to write binary?

A simplified example of what I'm trying to do, but the `copy` statement is going to write ASCII to my binary file:

```
ofstream foo("foo.txt", ios_base::binary);
vector<int> bar = {13, 42};

copy(bar.cbegin(), bar.cend(), ostream_iterator<decltype(bar)::value_type>(foo));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works, but you will have to explicitely use an `ostream_iterator<char>`.

Example (includes omitted for brievety):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::vector<int> arr;

    std::ofstream fd("foo.txt", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);

    for (int i=0; i<256; i++) arr.push_back(i);

    std::ostream_iterator<char> oi(fd);
    std::copy(arr.begin(), arr.end(), oi);
    fd.close();
    return 0;
}
```

will write the 256 bytes for 0 to 255 in foo.txt.

---

Above assumed that you wanted to write directly the value of the int as a char to the file. From your comment, you want to write the int value as a 4 bytes value (assuming int32_t) in native host endianness. I would use an auxilliary class to do the job:

```
class bint {
private:
    char c[sizeof(int)];

public:
    bint(const int i) { // allows bint b = 5;
        ::memcpy(c, &i, sizeof(c));
    }
    operator int() const {  // allows : bint b = 5; int i=b => gives i=5
        int i;
        ::memcpy(&i, c, sizeof(int));
        return i;
    }
    const char *getBytes() const { // gives public read-only access to the bytes
        return c;
    }
};

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const bint& b) {
    out.write(b.getBytes(), sizeof(int));
    return out;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::vector<int> arr;

    std::ofstream fd("foo.txt", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);

    for (int i=0; i<256; i++) arr.push_back(i);

    std::ostream_iterator<bint> oi(fd);
    std::copy(arr.begin(), arr.end(), oi);
    fd.close();
    return 0;
}
```

This one writes 1024 bytes (for integer of size 4) containing the representations of the 256 first integers. It would automatically adapts to other sizes of int.

Comment: My heart leaped when I saw this. But alas it does not work. It simply casts each `int` to a `char` and then outputs that ASCII char to the stream. [This example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8c945a72877458f) shows the result: `"wrong value 1: 842281777
wrong value 2: 0
wrong value 3: 0
wrong value 4: 0
right value 1: 49
right value 2: 51
right value 3: 52
right value 4: 50"`

Comment: @JonathanMee: I thought that was what you expected. What result do you want for `{13, 42}`?

Comment: I am writing to integers in binary format. When I read two integers in binary format I expect them to be the same round trip, so I expect 13, 42. In the example I linked you can see how `read` and `write` accomplish this correctly. Giving me an unchanged round trip.

Comment: @JonathanMee: I've understood. I must think again to my solution... I should give you something in a while

Comment: Interesting a wrapper class... I hadn't considered that angle of attack.

Comment: After a brief and exciting consideration of `ostreambuf_iterator` I am again forced to accept this is the only option within the standard (beyond writing my own iterator.) I'll again state that if only an [InputIterator or ForwardIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator#Iterator_categories) are needed for the algorithm inputs [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32073224/2642059) is a better choice.

Comment: Also this answer could be improved by [making `c` a reference](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/25158901#25158901) and by using a `ostreambuf_iterator` instead of an `ostream_iterator`.

Answer (score 5):

[`ostreambuf_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostreambuf_iterator) is more appropriate than `ostream_iterator`. It's much lighter weight and it does no formatting. It takes a template argument for the character type, so the only choice compatible with most streams is `std::ostream_iterator< char >`.

Be sure to open the stream in binary mode. The standard stream buffers, by the way, are never opened in binary mode.

Comment: I looked every where for this. Even wrote a [hackish answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32073224/2642059) to get a solution. This is the correct answer. I'll accept after I leave some time for this answer to garner upvotes.

Comment: @JonathanMee If you like :) . Be careful when unaccepting answers, though; if I hadn't edited after the unaccept you would never be able to accept it again.

Comment: Ugh, it looks like I still need my hackish answer. `ostreambuf_iterator` only accepts `char`s. Meaning that like my answer this won't work for anything but [InputIterator or ForwardIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator#Iterator_categories), or you'll have to also use a wrapper or specialized iterators.

Comment: @JonathanMee Iterators by definition work with only one type. It sounds like you want a binary serialization library. You do want formatting, just not into text. There are various approaches, but you might ask a more specific question.

Comment: The question asks for an iterator that works with standard algorithms. Algorithms like `reverse_copy` or `partial_sort_copy` are disaster for this answer or my hack.

Comment: @JonathanMee You can't read a file randomly or in reverse. You can  write code to do so, but it will be horribly inefficient since essentially every `seek` operation goes to the kernel. Copy the data into memory, then process it with ordinary iterators (pointers, even).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87278/discussion-between-jonathan-mee-and-potatoswatter).

Answer (score 1):

For algorithms that only use an [InputIterator or ForwardIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator#Iterator_categories) for the input, a simple cast is sufficient. For more complex algorithms [writing a wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32052256/2642059), writing a specialized iterator, or using Boost functionality may be necessary. Provided the algorithm input aligns with those conditions, something like this will work:

```
ofstream foo("foo.txt", ios_base::binary);
vector<int> bar = {13, 42};

copy(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&*bar.cbegin()), reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&*bar.cend()), ostreambuf_iterator(foo));
```

Obviously this needs to be round trip certified before it can be considered dependable. Validating that the values in `output` are consecutive can be tedious so code was hijacked [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27861373/2642059) to do that:

```
ofstream foo("foo.txt", ios::binary);
vector<int> bar(numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max() + 1);

iota(bar.begin(), bar.end(), 0);

copy(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&*bar.data()), reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&*bar.data() + bar.size()), ostreambuf_iterator<char>(foo));
foo.close();

ifstream file_read("foo.txt", ios::binary);
vector<decltype(bar)::value_type> output(bar.size());

copy(istreambuf_iterator<char>(file_read), istreambuf_iterator<char>(), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&*output.data()));

cout << "First element: " << output.front() << "\nLast element: " << output.back() << "\nAny non-consecutive elements: " << (output.cend() == mismatch(output.cbegin(), prev(output.cend()), next(output.cbegin()), [](auto first1, auto first2) { return first1 + 1 == first2; }).second ? "no\n" : "yes\n");
```

The [output from this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3032bf11dea2fc87) demonstrates that this method is actually successful:

> First element: 0
>   Last element: 255
>   Any non-consecutive elements: no

Although not every possible `int` was tried, every possible `char` was tried, and since any `int` can be made up of a collection of `char`s this demonstrates that any collection of `int`s is streamable this way.

Comment: The standard does require the a char has the weaker alignement. 3.11 Alignement §6 (from standard C++11 draft n4296) says: *the narrow character types shall have the weakest alignment requirement. [ Note: This enables the narrow character types to be used as the underlying type for an aligned memory area -- end note]*. That implies that `sizeof(T)` must be a multiple of `sizeof(char)`

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks, I didn't know that. I've edited accordingly.